# how to create an infinite List loop

Tags: flame

I tried to create an infinite scrolling effect which is similar to a slot machine, I have done such things just with flutter and cupertino widget, but with flame I have no clue how to create it,
for instance this is my code:

```
late List<GemComponent> firstColumnGemList;
late PositionComponent firstSlotColumn;
late List<Sprite> _sprites;
```

and here is for onload method:

```
_sprites = ['some elements for slotmachine']

firstColumnGemList = List.generate(_sprites.length, (index) {
  return GemComponent(
    gemSprite: _sprites[index],
    gemSize: gemSize,
    gemPosition: Vector2(0, index * gemSize.y),
    // position: position
  );
});

firstSlotColumn = PositionComponent(
  position: Vector2(0, 0),
  size: gemSize,
);

firstColumnGemList.forEach((element) {
  firstSlotColumn.add(element);
});

add(firstSlotColumn);

var firstMoveEffect = MoveEffect.by(
  Vector2(0, -5 * gemSize.y),
  EffectController(duration: 1, curve: Curves.easeOut),
);

firstSlotColumn.add(firstMoveEffect);
```

I think the code is not clean, and not to mention I have to create three columns, so everything has to multiple three times.
I understand how to remove this GemComponent if it is out of screen, but I have no clue to add a GemComponent while firstSlotColumn is scrolling, or is there any inspiration to create such effect instead of MoveEffect?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `SpriteComponent`s and use `MoveToEffect`s on them, then you can also get a curve for the spin (so that it spins slower in the beginning and then speeds up for example).

So first you could create a `PositionComponent` that will represent each column, since you will need multiple columns:

```dart
class ColumnComponent extend PositionComponent {
  ColumnComponent(super.position) : super(size: Vector2(<<width>>, <<height>>));

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    // Next step
  }
}
```

Then in the `onLoad` method you can create one `SpriteComponent` per gem and store in a list. Then you can position the first first three  (or however many you want visible) + one underneath each other adding them as children to the `ColumnComponent`.

The first component should be added outside of the `ColumnComponent` so that it can spin in later, let's call that one -1. To cover the -1 component and the components spinning out of view you have to either use a `CropComponent` to wrap the `ColumnComponent` or simply put a component on top of the `ColumnComponent`s so that only the part of the columns that you want visible are in view (you can put another component on top by setting the `priority` higher than what the `ColumnComponent` has).

When you want to start the spin you add a `MoveToEffect` that moves each sprite to the bottom of the `ColumnComponent` and in the `MoveToEffect` you add the `onComplete` callback and in that one you add the next component in your list at the -1 position, and use for the component that just completed its effect you do `component.removeFromParent()` and add it at the end of your list with gem components.

You also have to add some logic for when it should stop spinning, but that should be trivial once you got it spinning.

Comment: hi spydon thank you again for you detailed explanation and clue, with adding an spriteComponent in onComplete of MoveToEffect is what I didnt come up. It may achieve my goal, but in this way I have to put MoveToEffect to each individuell SpriteComponent in ColumnComponent right? Which could make somehow low fps? I'm not familiar with this thing, I thought in async keeping adding a new SpriteComponent while slotmachine is running could look ugly... So for now my solution is edit the whole sprite as just one complete column image, so I just have one SpriteComponent and spin it:)

Comment: For now it works fun, I just need to calculate the position of this SpriteComponent and use MoveToEffect as you mentioned. thank you again as always, I will keep working with flame which works perfect for me:)

Comment: You'd have to add a loooot of components before it would be a problem with the effects. You don't have to add a new component on each time, you can remove them from their parent and then re-use them later when it is their turn to show again. It works fine just adding the whole column as a sprite too, it's a little bit harder to modify it though, but whatever works for you!